# Change text on cursor position

Tags: jquery, position, mousemove, onmousemove

I am trying to change a text based on the cursor position.
It is working but the change sensitivity is way to fast.
So I was wondering if there is a way to adjust this, that the change isn't that fast.

```js
var text = ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Strawberry', 'Melon']
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  var randomItem = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
  var div = $("#message");

  div.stop().animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 1, function() {
    $(this).text(randomItem);
    $(this).stop().animate({
      "opacity": "1"
    }, 1);
  });
});
```

```css
#message { font-size: 54px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">Move the mouse.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2raaa/23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you can formulate a better solution. In your case, you only focus on mouse movement, since you want to increase the sensitivity you can observe actual position of the mouse:

```js
var text = ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Strawberry', 'Melon']
var pos = {x: 0, y:0};
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  var randomItem = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
  var div = $("#message");
  if (event.pageX > pos.x+30 || event.pageY > pos.y+30 || event.pageY < pos.y -30 || event.pageX < pos.x-30) {
    pos.x = event.pageX;
    pos.y = event.pageY;
    div.stop().animate({
      "opacity": "1"
    }, 1, function() {
      $(this).text(randomItem);
      $(this).stop().animate({
        "opacity": "1"
      }, 1);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#message { font-size: 54px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">Move the mouse.</div>
```

Comment: NNICE. Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Idan :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the duration property of the jquery animate.

here is a working plunker :

```
var text = ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Strawberry', 'Melon']
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  var randomItem = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];

  var div = $("#message");
  div.stop().animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, 50, function() {
    $(this).text(randomItem);
    $(this).stop().animate({
      "opacity": "1"
    }, 1);
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2raaa/27/

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer HellYeah. I also tried this, but the result wasn't good, it doenst feels like its based on the mouse movement, because sometimes it is still changing when you stopped moving.